# C: Determine whether a pointer exists inside an array and print the following items

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, printing

I need to write a function which gets an array, it's size and a pointer, I need to check if the pointer exists in the array and if so, print all the elements after it and i'm not allowed to create local variables or use [].
This is what i did to find whether the pointer exists or not.

```
void printAfterX(int* arr, int n, int* x)
{
    if (x < (arr + n) && x >= arr)
    {

    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the problem? What you tried, did it work? Expand the actual problem a bit please?

Comment: I don't know how to print the elements after it

Comment: Is this a homework assignment you want us to solve for you?

Comment: No, i'm learning by myself and i can't figure out how to solve this question.

Comment: Is `x` a pointer to the value which should be searched in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the pointer exists

```
for(x; x < (arr + n); x++){
    printf("%i\n", *x);
}
```

should do the job

Comment: it should if the if statement returns true; this snipped is inside the if statement

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you two hints:

(1) Function parameters are l-values.

(2) Eventually recursion.

You should try both, even if recusion is an overkill here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the operator `+` for this situation who works exactly like [] on pointers at this situation.
 
At Pseudo it's look like that:

```
void printAfterX(int* arr, int n, int* x)
{
    if arr < x < arr+n{
          print array(x)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your main data type is **int**, and that you want to match the content pointed by the pointer (not the pointer itself), here's a working solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printAfterX(int*, int, int*);

int main() {
    int array[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int sizeOfArray = 10;
    int *pointerX = &array[4];

    printAfterX(array, sizeOfArray, pointerX);

    return 0;
}

void printAfterX(int* arr, int n, int* x) {
    // Iterates over given array
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // If contents match
        if(*(arr + i) == *x) {
            for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                // Print all elements after found element
                // (not-inclusive, i.e. j = i + 1)
                printf("%d ", *(arr + j));
            }
            break; // break outer loop, because job's done
        }
    }
    printf("\n"); // Line feed at end of iteration
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
bool SearchForPointer(int* arr, int n, int* x)
{ 
    if( 0 == n)
        return false;

    if( arr == x)
    {
        while( --n)
        { 
            arr++;
            ::printf( "Pointer: 0x%08X; Value: %d;\r\n", (intptr_t)(arr), *(arr));
        }

        return true;
    }

    return SearchForPointer( ++arr, --n, x);
}


int main()
{
    int     arr[]   = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int*    p       = arr+2;

    ::printf( "Searching for: p = 0x%08X; value: %d\r\n", (intptr_t)p, *p);

    SearchForPointer( arr, 5, p);


    return 0;
}
```